# Circular iteration in bash

Tags: bash

I'd have a couple of possible (say string) values: `a b c`. I'd like a to switch from one to another in a circular way:

```
if [ "$value" == "a" ]; then value=b
elif [ "$value" == "b"]; then value=c
elif [ "$value" == "c"]; then value=a
fi
```

With method like this, Can this be done in a more efficient way, so that I could support many options, like `a b c ... z`?

Comment: What if `a->b` and `b->a` make a circular?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
get_next()
{
    __current_i=${__current_i:- 0} # global variable that saves index of current value
    [ $__current_i -ge $# ] && __current_i=0 # if we exceed the number of values, then reset to zero
    shift $__current_i # move to current value
    ((__current_i++)) # increment index
    echo $1
}

val="a b c d"

get_next $val
get_next $val
get_next $val
get_next $val
get_next $val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash arrays

```
vals=('a' 'b' 'c')
value=$1

max=$(( ${#vals[@]} - 1 ))
count=0
while [ "$value" != "${vals[count]}" ]
do
   count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done
if [ $count -eq $max ]; then
   count=0
else
   count=$(( $count + 1 ))
fi
echo ${vals[count]}
```

Comment: can also use the mod operator and the array length to simplify your if else construct

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

This will do what you want:

```
while true; do
  for x in a b c; do
    echo "$x"
  done
done
```

Comment: echo a b c is even simpler